# XCGLogger version 4.0.0 and CocoaPods error

Tags: cocoapods, xcglogger

I am trying to use CocoaPods to acquire XCGLogger for Swift 3.  I have tried specifying version 4.0.0 and 4.0.0-beta.3 in my pod file.  However when I run a pod update or pod install I get the following error:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `XCGLogger (~> 4.0.0-beta.3)` required by `Podfile`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `Podfile`:

`pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'git@github.com:DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_3.0'`

Specifying the branch will mean you'll get updates as I push them, Beta 4 etc.

Comment: Gave that a shot but I am getting an error:
[!] Error installing XCGLogger
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git /var/folders/l2/6n2_1bb97fjd7zhytj1_tstr0000gn/T/d20160913-45618-iakkpy --single-branch --depth 1 --branch swift_3.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/l2/6n2_1bb97fjd7zhytj1_tstr0000gn/T/d20160913-45618-iakkpy'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Ah, if you don't have a public key set up for Github (I recommend you do), then change the source from `git@...` to `https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git` and use HTTPS instead of ssh.